# Clearer content in all TextBoxes and ComboBoxes

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to clear all the content in the TextBoxes and ComboBoxes in my VBA UserForm except the TextBox named 'TxtTanggal'.

```vb
Private Sub Tmbl_Del_Click()
    Dim sampah As TextBox
    Dim sampah2 As ComboBox
    
    For Each sampah In Jurnal
    If IsEmpty(sampah) Then
        If sampah.Name <> TxtTanggal Then
            sampah.Value = ""
        End If
    End If
    Next
    For Each sampah2 In Jurnal
        sampah2.Value = ""
    Next
End Sub
```

But I get an error

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Objects `TextBox` don't have property `Value`. So `sampah.Value = ""` will raise an error. Did you try `sampah.Text = ""`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adopting the following code, which loops through each control, and checks whether the control is either a TextBox or ComboBox.  If so, it clears the content, unless the control is named "TextBox1".

```
Dim ctrl As Control

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
        Case "TextBox", "ComboBox"
            If ctrl.Name <> "TextBox1" Then
                ctrl.Value = ""
            End If
    End Select
Next ctrl
```